# Unable to change Value in TextInput when using props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this class that shows two TextInputs, initially the values are empty but then another component send the values by props. The problem is that I also want to edit them in this component but its not working properly. When I receive the values and then I change them, then if I copy them with the Button it wont copy the value in the state.
I added a userInitialized and passInitialized booleans that are set to true if the values are changed by typing and not for passing props.
Any idea? Thanks.

```
export default class BotomQRScanner extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            userField: this.props.user,
            userInitialized: false,
            passInitialized: false,
            passwordField: this.props.pass
        }
    }

    handleUserChange(value){
    this.setState({userField: value, userInitialized: true});
  }

    handlePasswordChange(value){
    this.setState({passwordField: value, passInitialized: true});
  }

    render(){


        return (
            <View style={{height: '100%', width: '100%', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-around'}}>

            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <TextInput
                onChangeText={(value) => this.handleUserChange(value)}
                style={{textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 16, height: 50, width: 200}}
                autoCapitalize = 'none'
                autoCorrect={false}
                selectTextOnFocus={true}
                placeholder={'username'}
                selectionColor={'#428AF8'}
                value={this.state.userInitialized? this.state.userField : this.props.user}
              />
              <Button
              title="copy"
              onPress={() => {
              Clipboard.setString(this.state.userInitialized? this.state.userField : this.props.user)
            }}
            />
          </View>

          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <TextInput
                onChangeText={(value) => this.handlePasswordChange(value)}
                style={{textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 16, height: 80, width: 200}}
                autoCapitalize = 'none'
                autoCorrect={false}
                selectTextOnFocus={true}
                placeholder={'password'}
                value={this.state.passInitialized? this.state.passField : this.props.pass}
              />
              <Button
              title="copy"
              onPress={() => {
              Clipboard.setString(this.state.passInitialized? this.state.passField : this.props.pass)
            }}
            />
          </View>

            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your  handleUserChange and handlePasswordChange functions are not binded, please bind them or use arrow functions.

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb still doesnt work, sometimes when i want to copy the password with the Button and I paste it theres nothing, doesnt copy the value. The weird thing is that is copying the user correctly. But I remember yesterday it happened the opposite.

Comment: Can you create a minimal example of your code and share it i.e codeSandbox?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `handleUserChange` and `handlePasswordChange` to an arrow function like.

```
  handleUserChange = value => {
    this.setState({userField: value, userInitialized: true});
    }
```

AND

```
 handlePasswordChange = value =>{
    this.setState({passwordField: value, passInitialized: true});
    }
```

So your functions will get called and your state variable values get updated.

Comment: still doesnt work, sometimes when i want to copy the password with the Button and I paste it theres nothing, doesnt copy the value. The weird thing is that is copying the user correctly. But I remember yesterday it happened the opposite.

Comment: You can initialize the state from props using getDerrivedStateFromProps method and can use the state value directly I mean assign it and remove that condition.

Comment: but will it work if I also want to modify the values? Example: 1. Sent values by props 2. I receive and place the values in the TextInputs 3. I modify the values in the TextInputs

Comment: Yes, it should have to be like, when you receive the value from props it will get assigned to a state value. if you change the state value using setState method in that case also the state value will get change and input will always have the value from state value.

Comment: I dont see this will help, how can I make the TextInputs change when onChangeText is called?